# R Leaflet: Is it possible to have a two column layer control panel?

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with 75 overlay groups that I want to turn visible/invisible using the layer control panel. The problem is, that with that amount of groups my layer control panel reaches the end of my map and therefore not all of the groups are visible in the layers control panel.

The following minimal reproducible example shows the problem in detail:

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet(width = 400, height = 100) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  # Overlay groups
  addCircleMarkers(lng = 9, lat = 47, color = 'red', group = 'red') %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = 8, lat = 46, color = 'blue', group = 'blue') %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = 8, lat = 47, color = 'green', group = 'green') %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = 9, lat = 46, color = 'yellow', group = 'yellow') %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = 8.5, lat = 46.5, color = 'purple', group = 'purple') %>%
  # Layers control
  addLayersControl(
    overlayGroups = c('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple'),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE))
```

This leads to the following map where the `purple` point is not available on the layers control panel
[image]

Is there a possibility to force the layers control panel to arrange the layers in more than one column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. It doesn't use a multi column layout, but works with an automated overflow on the layers control panel, which allows to navigate to all layers.

Since the `addLayersControl` function doesn't have the parameters to control the column layout of the Layers Control, one has to twerk around with `JavaScript` and `CSS` to establish the multi column layout.
On the search for an really easy alternative I've stumbled upon the following on
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/aoImrdIoF2Q

```
.leaflet-control-layers {
  max-height: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

This does establish an auto overflow layout which is nearly as good as the two column layout for my application.
This snippet needs to be placed in the `CSS` section of the .html File containing the leaflet-map. So after 'knitting' the leaflet map to a .html File you have to reopen the .html file and place that snippet in the `<body>` section of the .html file.

```
    <body>
    <style type="text/css">
      .leaflet-control-layers {
        max-height: 60px;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>
    ...<rest of document>...
    </body>
```

The result is a layers control panel that allows to navigate through all layers.

Scrolled up:
[image: layers control panel upper position]
Scrolled down:
[image: layers control panel scrolled down]

Comment: How do you open a leaflet html file created in R, in a way that it is readable to the human eye?
By saving a leaflet map from R (by doing _Export/Save as Web Page_ in RStudio Viewer), the resulting html file is not organized the same way as your example, but as a unicoded file.

Comment: @YGS I use RStudio to open it. They are always readable (and organized as in my example..)

Comment: It's true that the `<body>` section is rather clean compared to the actual map data. For other people who, like me, didn't know html scripts could be open in R, go to _File/Open File_ and select the html file.
In my case, the `<body>` section needed to be edited a little: I'm posting the edit as an answer (if that's allowed).

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you have a couple of solutions... 
More elegant, cleaner and harder would be to modify the original leaflet-control-layer control or create a new one.

See [leaflet-src.js](https://code.google.com/p/monorail-samples/source/browse/branches/opengeocoder/trunk/dist/leaflet-src.js?r=289) on how 'leaflet-control-layers' div is created and you'll see what I am talking about.

Easier and 'dirtier' solution would be to use jQuery after the layers are added, go over the 'leaflet-control-layers-base' div, count it and apply some custom css that will add elements that have an index of 4 and above (for example) to another div which would be on the right from the first one (not a difficult thing to do right?). Of course you can measure the height of the map and compare it to the height of the div containing your layers and base your calculation on that (this would be a more generic solution).

So the answer is YES, you can do that.

Comment: Do you have by chance a working example (or link to one) of how I can add `jQuery`'s and `CSS` to my R Code? ..I never walked that line so far, so I'll be glad to have some guidance..

Comment: Never tried to include it with R. If this doesn't work you can always modify the original leaflet source code as I mentioned first. This will work 100%

Answer (score 1):

Following @symbolrush's answer, the `<body>` section may need to be edited a little if it already contains parameters.

Before (html file created by leaflet):

```
...
</head>
<body style="background-color:white;">
<div id="htmlwidget_container">
...
```

After @symbolrush's edits:

```
...
</head>
<body>
<style="background-color:white;"></style> #might not be necessary
<style type="text/css">
      .leaflet-control-layers {
        max-height: 600px;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>
<div id="htmlwidget_container">
...
```